# Common play way for both audio and video files

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer

I have multiple files in my document directory, the files are `mp3`, `mp4` and `avi` format types.
I need to play any of them in a player without worrying about its format type.
For the audio files, i use this approach:

```
//Play the file
    NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

                  NSError *err;
                  audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileUrl error:&err];

                  if (audioPlayer == nil)
                  NSLog(@"%@",[err description]);
                  else
                  [audioPlayer play];
```

Is there any common way/player for all audios/videos files (something like Microsoft media player).

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `MPMoviePlayerViewController` component. Example (this will show the controller as modal) :

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:player animated:YES];
```

You'll find documentation here : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller_class/Reference/Reference.html